# PHP Echo HTML tags around function result (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to echo html tags to the output of this function (below) but I am having a hard time placing them correctly. 
For starters I just want to echo a `<ul></ul>` around the output that is already a list item.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function my_text_after_content() {
$users = get_users(['role__in' => ['Contributor']]);
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $ids[] = $user->ID;
}

if(is_page(400)) {
    wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 1,
        'include'       => $ids
    ));
} };
add_action('themify_content_after', 'my_text_after_content');
```

I have tried adding the following:

```
function my_text_after_content() {
$users = get_users(['role__in' => ['Contributor']]);
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $ids[] = $user->ID;
}

if(is_page(400)) {
    echo '<ul>' . wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 1,
        'include'       => $ids
    )); . '</ul>';
} 


};
add_action('themify_content_after', 'my_text_after_content');
```

But this returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ids variable is not defined local variable. I added it.

```
function my_text_after_content() {
$users = get_users(['role__in' => ['Contributor']]);
$ids = [];
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $ids[] = $user->ID;
}

if(is_page(400)) {
    echo '<ul>' . wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 1,
        'include'       => $ids
    )); . '</ul>';
}

};
add_action('themify_content_after', 'my_text_after_content');
```

Comment: This still returns an error for me. Do you know if my concatenation is correct?

Comment: )); . '</ul>';   please remove ";".

Comment: function my_text_after_content() {
 $users = get_users(['role__in' => ['Contributor']]);
 $ids = [];
 foreach( $users as $user ){
  $ids[] = $user->ID;
 }

 ?>
 <ul>
 <?php 
 wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 1,
  'include'       => $ids,
  'hide_empty' => true,
 ));
 ?> 
 </ul>

 <?php

};
 add_action('themify_content_after', 'my_text_after_content');

Comment: I mean it just shows me the white screen when I upload that code. This is in my functions.php file btw.

Comment: I think that the code is not problem for me. Could you add the code. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);